# Alternative to Font Awesome

Tags: web-development, vector-graphics

I use Font Awesome, but most of the icons I need are in the Pro Licence. Is there any free alternative to Font Awesome including a CDN like Font Awesome ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Friconix](https://friconix.com) is my favorite Font Awesome alternative

- All the icons are free
- it uses CDN
- Easy to customize (explanations on the home page and [Quick Started Guide](https://friconix.com/start/) are clear)

I already requested an icon, it was updated in less than 24 hours !